# [vuex]unknown action type: getPackagingList

Tags: vuejs2, vuex

i'm using vuex with namespace, i created à store for vuex, when i call the action  i have  error [vuex] unknown action type: getPackagingList , i checked typo of all things, but without result:
store(index.js):

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import state from './state';
import * as getters from './getters';
import * as mutations from './mutations';
import * as actions from './actions';
import packaging from './modules/item/packaging'
Vue.use(Vuex);
export default new Vuex.Store({
    namespaced: true,
    state,
    getters,
    actions,
    mutations,
    modules: {  
            packaging,
    }
})
```

index.js(of packahing):

```js
import state from './state';
import * as getters from './getters';
import * as mutations from './mutations';
import * as actions from './actions';
export default {
    namespaced: true,
    state,
    getters,
    actions,
    mutations
};
```

actions.js:

```js
import axios from 'axios'
import Vue from 'vue'
export const getPackagingList = ({ commit }) => {
        axios.get("product/packaging/index", {
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            //  withCredentials: true //sent with cookie
            Authorization: "Bearer " + Vue.$cookies.get("jwt"),
          },
        })
        .then(res => {
            commit("SET_PACKAGING", res.data);
        })
  };
```

mutations.js

```js
export const SET_PACKAGING = (state, packagingList) => {
    state.packagingList= packagingList;
  };
```

state.js

```js
export default {
    packagingList:[],
    packagingId : null,
}
```

call action on mycomponent.vue:

```js
mounted() {
    this.getPackagingList();
}
methods: {
    ...mapActions(['getPackagingList']),
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Try this

```js
mounted() {
    this.getPackagingList();
}
methods: {
    ...mapActions('packaging', ['getPackagingList']),
}
```